# Postgis query on 3D cube does not use index

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d

I am testing Postgis on the follow query:

```
SELECT * FROM particles 
WHERE position  &&& 
'LINESTRING(0.08537 0.0738 0.0145,0.0953 0.0837 0.0345)';
```

that returns about 100k rows from a data set of about 100M. The schema of the table is

```
Table "public.particles"
  Column  |       Type       | Modifiers 
----------+------------------+-----------
 partid   | integer          | not null
 time     | double precision | not null
 position | geometry         | 
Indexes:
    "particles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (partid, "time")
    "particles_the_geom_gist" gist ("position")
Check constraints:
    "enforce_dims_the_geom" CHECK (st_ndims("position") = 3)
```

Even tought I have an index on the attribute position, the query is always executed  with a full table scan and  so it is  particularly slow.

I also tried

```
set enable_seqscan = off;
```

but it did not change anything.

Using different query like,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM particles WHERE ST_3DDWithin(position, 'SRID=4326;POINT(0.08537 0.0738 0.0145)',0.01);
```

which retrieves objects within a give distance from a point, Postgres uses the index, why it doesn't for the other  query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably created a 2d index, not an n-d index, which is what the &&& operator uses.

```
CREATE INDEX particles_gix ON particles USING GIST (position gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

Comment: Thank you! I took some hours to recreate the new index but now it works! Thanks!